# IntelliJ says that it cannot resolve the getValue()

Tags: java

So we have a project where we're supposed to make a simple "computer", in that computer we have a memory with addresses that points to different kinds of words.

```
public interface Word extends Operable {
    Word add(Word word1, Word word2);
    Word mul(Word word1, Word word2);
}
```

We're then supposed to be able to operate on these words, two of those operations are add and mul. The Word interface is then implemented in the various word subclasses.

```
public class ByteWord implements Word {
    private Byte value;

    public ByteWord(String stringValue) {
        this.value = Byte.parseByte(stringValue);
    }

    @java.lang.Override
    public ByteWord add(Word word1, Word word2) {
        this.value = word1.getValue() + word2.getValue();
        return this;
    }

    @java.lang.Override
    public ByteWord mul(Word word1, Word word2) {
        this.value = word1.getValue() * word2.getValue();
        return this;
    }

    private Byte getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

The problem here is that IntelliJ says that it cannot resolve the getValue() and another warning that says that getValue() is never used.

Changing the type of word1 and word2 to ByteWord will solve this problem but give another error saying we're not actually adding in the unimplemented method from Word.

And casting them to the correct wordtype where we're assigning the value to this.value since we know that we will always send in a certain type will say that Java expected byte buy got int from adding two bytes together.

Would love any type of input that might solve my problem here, thanks in advance!

Comment: This is not related to IntelliJ at all. This is expected as Word does not have a Method getValue(), only ByteWord has that. It's not a valid Java Programm.

Comment: @manf Alright, removed the IntelliJ tag. But putting getValue in word wont work since different wordtypes returns different types of values (Long and Byte in it's current state). But I'm under the impression that I dont have to have all the subclasses methods in any implemented interface above, just the ones that might exist and be similiar between different subclasses

Comment: Well you need to think about the behavior of adding or multiplying two independent words then. You could use casting to make it work with itself, but that does not help you in general. Alternatively you might want to use generics. See Comparable interface.

Answer (score 1):

```
private Byte getValue() {
    return value;
}
```

Is a method that belongs to the `ByteWord` class not `Word` so you cannot call `word1.getValue()`. The warning you are getting is because you are never calling it on a `ByteWord` object.

> Changing the type of word1 and word2 to ByteWord will solve this problem but give another error saying we're not actually adding in the unimplemented method from Word.

This is because you define the method in `Word` as accepting `Word` parameters.

Answer (score 0):

As other answers said, the reason the compiler cannot find the `getValue()` method is because `word1` and `word2` are `Word` objects, and `Word` doesn't have a `getValue()` method so you cannot call it on `Word` objects. The method is private to `ByteWord`, so you can only call it on `ByteWord` objects specifically.

But... Does it make sense for `word1` and `word2` to be `Word`s?
Does it make sense for a `ByteWord` to `mul` two `Word`s if they are not `ByteWord`s themselves?
If I had a `DWord` class, would it make sense to do this?

```
DWord dword = new DWord(10);
ByteWord byte1 = new ByteWord(1);
ByteWord byte2 = new ByteWord(2);
dword.add(byte1, byte2);
```

I don't think so. Wouldn't it make more sense for `ByteWord`s to operate with `ByteWord`s and for `DWord`s to operate with other `DWords`?
Then what you probably need to do is make the interface generic:

```
public interface Word<T extends Word> extends Operable {
    T add(T word1, T word2);
    T mul(T word1, T word2);
}
```

So each class implements it accordingly:

```
public class ByteWord implements Word<ByteWord> {
    private Byte value;

    public ByteWord(String stringValue) {
        this.value = Byte.parseByte(stringValue);
    }

    @Override
    public ByteWord add(ByteWord word1, ByteWord word2) {
        this.value = (byte) (word1.getValue() + word2.getValue());
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public ByteWord mul(ByteWord word1, ByteWord word2) {
        this.value = (byte) (word1.getValue() * word2.getValue());
        return this;
    }

    private Byte getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}

public class DWord implements Word<DWord> {
    private Integer value;

    public DWord(String stringValue) {
        this.value = Integer.parseInt(stringValue);
    }

    @Override
    public DWord add(DWord word1, DWord word2) {
        this.value = word1.getValue() + word2.getValue();
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public DWord mul(DWord word1, DWord word2) {
        this.value = word1.getValue() * word2.getValue();
        return this;
    }

    private Integer getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Now you can write:

```
    ByteWord byte1 = new ByteWord("1");
    byte1.add(new ByteWord("2"), new ByteWord("3"));
    System.out.println("byte1 = " + byte1.value);
```

And have it output:

> `byte1 = 5`

And also write:

```
    byte1.add(new DWord("2"), new DWord("3"));
```

And see that it doesn't compile because `DWord`s are not `ByteWord`s.

But that still would be weird, because what's the point of having an initial `value` if you are never going to use it in your calculations?

So, then again probably, it'd make even more sense to have the methods operate on the current value of the `Word`, receiving only one parameter:

```
public interface Word<T extends Word> extends Operable {
    T add(T word1);
    T mul(T word1);
}

public class ByteWord implements Word<ByteWord> {
    private Byte value;

    public ByteWord(String stringValue) {
        this.value = Byte.parseByte(stringValue);
    }

    @Override
    public ByteWord add(ByteWord word1) {
        this.value = (byte) (this.value + word1.getValue());
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public ByteWord mul(ByteWord word1) {
        this.value = (byte) (this.value * word1.getValue());
        return this;
    }

    private Byte getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Finally, you can now write:

```
    ByteWord byte1 = new ByteWord("1");
    byte1.add(new ByteWord("2"));
    System.out.println("byte1 = " + byte1.value);
```

And have it output:

> `byte1 = 3`

Which in my opinion makes more sense.

However, I don't know if the code you included in your question is yours or your teacher's, and I don't know what parts you can modify and what parts you cannot, so I just hope that I gave you some insight.